# After running the AngularJs Project, I Found Errors like Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, node.js

"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: FileUploaderProvider <- FileUploader <- ReportsAddCtrl

What to do exactly for solving this issue .... i am totally new in AngularjS

Comment: You are injecting `FileUploader` into a service or controller but probably not adding it's module as a module dependency. Show us the basic outline code of your app

Comment: angular.module('clientApp')
.controller('ReportsAddCtrl', function ($scope, priority, caseType, caseReason, report, Image, status, $location, FileUploader) {
    $scope.priorities = priority.getList().$object;
    $scope.caseTypes = caseType.getList().$object;
    $scope.caseReasons = caseReason.getList().$object;
    $scope.report = {};
    $scope.report.title = genId();
    $scope.report.submitter = 'Current User';
    $scope.report.fromRole = 'Developer';
  });
};

Comment: don't drop code blobs into comments...edit the question itself so they can be formatted and read by all

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate four common causes of error:

- typos,
- if the controller is defined anywhere in your module,
- if all your dependencies you use in the controller are defined,
- if you try to inject $scope outside the controller.

For more detailed description of error you can read https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr